# Getting 404 on GCP VM while calling REST endpoint

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have successfully deployed a Get REST endpoint on local external tomcat, which I build using spring boot, I'm trying to deploy the same application on GCP compute engine VM in which tomcat 10 and jdk-11 is installed, but I'm getting the error 404 while accessing the same endpoint

please note the local tomcat version is 8 which is different from vm tomcat i.e. 10, I have enabled firewall at port 8080 for ingress traffic. also I have verified the server.xml configuration in both the environment is same.

here is the sample end point

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorld {    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "hello";
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class PestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(PestApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I m new with this gcp and tomcat environment,  so need help for debugging the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you [programmed the firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) to permit traffic to that port on that VM?

Comment: No i haven't,  because other sample applications have already deployed on tomcat and running well.